# Which units do I use in calculating heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics

The specific heat capacity of liquid water is $4.18 \, \text{J} \, \text{K}^{-1} \, \text{g}^{-1}$. Calculate the energy required to heat $1.0 \, \text{mol}$ of water from $298 \, \text{K}$ to $363 \, \text{K}$. 
My question is: Do I have to change the moles of water into grams or should I sub in $1.0$ into the formula for specific heat capacity?

Comment: General tip for any calculation: do the units. Literally write every number out along with the units (respectively placed in the numerator or denominator). Then go through the right side of the equation crossing everything out and make sure you get the units you would expect for your final quantity on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would have to change it to grams.

Units must be consistent. Specific heat is defined as the energy required to raise one gram of water by one kelvin. At atmospheric pressure in a closed container, the specific heat of water is 4.184 joules.

One mole of water is 18.016 grams. So:

$E =mc \Delta T $

Where $m$ is the mass of the water, $c$ is the specific heat capacity of water, $\Delta T $ is the change in temperature, and $E$ is the energy required. Substitute in your numbers, and you shall get the right answer:

$E = (18.016\ \mathrm{g})(\frac{4.184\ \mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{g\ K}})(363\ \mathrm{K} - 293\ \mathrm{K})$

$E = 5280\ \mathrm{J}$

If you wanted to use moles directly instead of converting to grams, you would have had to use the *molar heat capacity*. Generally, people prefer to use specific heat. Engineers sometimes use the *volumetric heat capacity* as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the operative value/g.  Have it act upon grams of sample.  Keep your units consistent.

Water boils at 373 K, so one presumes it is a reasonably closed container - or evaporation will skew the real world number, leveraged by surface area.  A mole of water is a little more than a tablespoon. Call it about 18 calories/K.